# НЕ работает авторизация PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, авторизация

Постоянно выводит **Логин или пароль не верны!**
Подскажите что не так

```
<?php
    //Запрашиваем настройки и для удобства делаем массив $d
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.php'; 
    $d = $_POST;

    //Проверка на пустышку
    if (!empty($d['email']) && !empty($d['password']) && isset($d['email']) && isset($d['password'])) {

        //Проверяем email
        if (filter_var($d['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == true) {

            //Обрабатываем поля
            $email = trim(mb_strtolower(htmlspecialchars($d['email'])));
            $password = trim(htmlspecialchars($d['password']));

            // Хешируем пароль
            $pass = pHash($d['password']);

            //Запрос в бд
            $logQuery = $dbc->prepare("SELECT login, password, fname FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :pass LIMIT 1");
            $params = array(
                'email' => $email,
                'pass' => $pass,
                 );
            $lQ = $logQuery->execute($params);

            //Проверяем данные
            if ($lQ != false && !empty($lQ->fetchAll)) {

                //Ура! Вы авторизованы, начинаем запоминание данных!
                echo 'OK';
                //тут будет дальшк код
                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$way.'">';

            } else {
                echo '<p class="red bold italic">Логин или пароль не верны!</p>';
                $dbc = null;
                die;
            }

        } else {
            echo '<p class="red bold">Вы ввели неправильный E-mail!</p>';
            $dbc = null;
            die;
        }

    } else {
        echo 'Вы не ввели логин и/или пароль!';
        $dbc = null;
        die;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код здесь, а не на стороннем ресурсе

Comment: ок,! исправил,!

Comment: Очевидно же что проблема в этой строчке `if ($lQ != false && !empty($lQ->fetchAll))`. Смотрите чему равен `$lQ`. `var_dump()` вам в помощь

Comment: bool(false) Я уже это видел

Comment: Ну и чего вы хотите от нас? Чтобы мы сказали что вы неправильно ввели логин или пароль? Или что он не соответствует хранимым в базе данных?

Comment: Он соответствует, я проверял хеш версию с записью в бд

Comment: Тогда напишите тут запрос, который отправляется в БД и дамп базы данных с этой строчкой, чтоб уж наверняка. Если вы используете PDO, то неплохо бы включить режим исключения в случае ошибки

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался. Причины 1. Ошибка в запросе: у меня столбца login нет 2. Запрос почему всё время возвращает bool.